# Mysql return count for last 7 days

Tags: mysql, database

I am having trouble to run the code below to count rows grouped by date as it returns wrong count for each days

```
SELECT DATE(Date) as days
      ,coalesce(count(credits),0) as credits 
from offer_process qa
left join ( SELECT DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL 30 DAY as day_series 
            from(SELECT 0 AS a 
                 UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2 
                 UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4
                 UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL SELECT 6
                ) as a 
          ) as qb
on DATE(Date) = DATE(Date) 
WHERE Date > DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 day) 
group by DATE(Date) 
order by DATE(Date) asc;
```

Insted of returning 1 for each rows for example, it returns 7, which is not true

Comment: probably the join ;o) in your join you have 7 rows ... each of which is joined with your outer table, your join condition is really not a condition as it is always true

Comment: Well, we only have your word for that, don't we? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Can you please re write the above code if possible? Would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one. It will return count of credits for a selected ID for each of the last 7 days.

```
SELECT (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL `day` DAY) AS `DayDate`, COUNT(`credits`) AS `credits`
FROM (
    SELECT 0 AS `day`
    UNION SELECT 1
    UNION SELECT 2
    UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5
    UNION SELECT 6
) AS `week`
LEFT JOIN `offer_process` ON DATE(`Date`) = (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL `day` DAY) AND `id` = 50
GROUP BY `DayDate`
ORDER BY `DayDate` ASC
```

Here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a6592/1

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
SELECT DATE(Date) as days
      ,coalesce(count(credits),0) as credits 
from offer_process qa
left join (SELECT DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL 30 DAY as day_series) as qb
on DATE(qa.Date) = DATE(qb.day_series) 
WHERE Date > DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 day) 
group by DATE(Date) 
order by DATE(Date);
```

Comment: That works great! I forgot to ask, how can I still show last 7 days with condition like id = 1, currently doesn't display unless there is an row with that id. So I tried "Where id = '1'", but as there isn't any rows with that id, it displays blank, but I want 0 even if no row with id =1

Comment: Please sample data for me to help you more.